# What is the difference between "run as administrator" context vs properties?

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have a old program designed for XP, which does not run properly in Windows 7 and UAC on.

If i start the program with right click and "Run as administrator" the program crashes with

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The requested operation requires elevation
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Tat.Tools.OskLayout.ShowKeypad()
   at Tat.Tools.OskLayout..ctor()
   at Tat.Tools.OskLayout.get_Run()
   at Tat.Tools.OskLayout.Main(String[] args)
```

If i set program properties -> compatibility -> "Run this program as an administrator" the program works.

I have to accept the UAC dialog in both cases, which is the expected behavior.

What is the difference between "Run as administrator" context menu and the property "Run this program as an administrator" ?

Comment: AFAIK UAC disabled...

Comment: Are you prompted to allow it to run with each setting?

Comment: @Moab UAC dialog in both cases

Comment: That's a strange problem for which I have no answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Q: What is the difference between "Run as administrator" context menu and the property "Run this program as an administrator" ?

A: There is no difference between them.

According to the sentence: **If i set program properties -> compatibility -> "Run this program as an administrator" the program works.** The program can run properly, I think because we set program **properties -> compatibility ->Run this program in compatibility mode**, it is not only because this program needs to run as an administrator.

Because the program designed for XP, now we run it in Windows 7, so we need run this program in compatibility mode, then we can run it properly.

Whether the program needs to run as an administrator depends on the program itself, some programs need to run as an administrator, and some programs do not need to run as an administrator.

Comment: I set the "Run this program as an administrator" by registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers with value "RUNASADMIN" cause i have to do it unattended. According to https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-compatibility.html compatibilty mode would be an additional entry. I am sorry, but compatibility mode is not an issue here.I also tried compatibility mode with no success.